# Python Function is not executed in the output

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, pyautogui

I am creating a camera application using opencv and pyautogui.The function is not getting evaluated.

```
from utils import CFEVideoConf, image_resize


def recog():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    save_path = 'saved-media/video.avi'
    frames_per_seconds = 24.0
    config = CFEVideoConf(cap, filepath=save_path, res='720p')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(save_path, config.video_type, frames_per_seconds, config.dims)

    while (True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        out.write(frame)
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            op = pyautogui.confirm("") 
            if op == 'OK':
                print("Out")
                break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

opt =pyautogui.confirm(text= 'Chose an option', title='Camcorder', buttons=['Record', 'Capture', 'Exit'])
if opt == 'START':
    print("Starting the app")
    recog()

if opt == 'Exit':
    print("Quit the app")
```

Please correct the mistakes if there are any.

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get tips how to improve your question.

Comment: Tagged as python

Answer (score 0):

The function `recog` is not getting evaluated because of below if statement

```
if opt == 'START':
```

There is no button named `START`. Your `confirm()` function displays a message box with `Record`, `Capture`, `Exit` buttons, but no `START` button. So, there is no way `confirm()` function returned value will be equal to `START`.

Comment: Thanks Anubhav, But that's my error when I copied the unedited file. Even After changing, it didnt work.